# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. while reading image from SharePoint online in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

**The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. while reading image from SharePoint online library in .Net Core 3.1 using HttpWebRequest or WebClient.**
Same code is working fine with older version on VS like VS 17 4.6.1.
Till now i am assuming , issue is in Nuget package **TTCUE.NetCore.SharepointOnline.CSOM.16.1.8029.1200**.
It is working fine if i am trying to create and get sharepoint list/ library data using ClientContext.
Bu it failed in getting data via HttpWebRequest or WebClient.
Can some one help me on this please.

Thanks,
Dinesh

Comment: This package [home page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TTCUE.NetCore.SharepointOnline.CSOM.16.1.8029.1200/) is invalid. Maybe you can share your code to help us better understand. And is 'VS 17 4.6.1'  .net framework on VS 2017?  CSOM authentication on .net core is a little different from .net framework, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard

Comment: Thanks Baker for reply, below is my code.

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("***","***");
request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36";
request.GetResponse()

Answer (score 0):

@Dinesh Negi,

> var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
> request.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("","");
> request.Method = "GET";
> request.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
> request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36";
> request.GetResponse()

`SharePointOnlineCredentials` is not available in .NET Standard (.net core), please check below section for more details:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard#key-differences-between-the-net-framework-version-and-the-net-standard-version

[image]

BR